# Trying to find a book about alien symbiote in a fantasy setting

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find a book about alien symbiote in a fantasy setting. 
I think it was a young adult book, but I’m not sure.

- People had found these aliens that they first bonded with native life and then bonded the resulting crystals to themselves giving them elementally themed powers.
- There were lab flashbacks and an AI I think doing them extractions as the world regressed.
- Oh yes, the humans were colonists but trapped and regressed.
- The main character ends up throwing a bunch of symbiotes together in desperate attempt to beat the baddie.
- It might have had "storm" in the name?

Comment: Probably Janny Wurts *Cycle of Fire*, does [this sound familiar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/28271/5930)?

Comment: Specifically it would be the book [Stormwarden](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/363917.Stormwarden) that does indeed have *storm* in the name.

Comment: Thank you, that is the book I was looking for.